# `thmtools.sty' not found - MikTex Console Issue?

Tags: packages, miktex, thmtools

Tried looking this up, but having trouble finding anything that was helpful.

I just recently built a new computer and installed MikTex on this new desktop. I took a file that compiled on my previous desktop and struggled to get it to compile on this new desktop. I kept getting the error:

> File "thmtools.sty" not found

I go into the MikTex console and look it up under packages and made sure it was installed. I tried restarting my computer, reinstalling the package, etc, but the error kept popping up. When finally looking into my files, I found the thmtools file, which does not contain any sty files. (It only downloaded dtx files.) I went to CTAN to manually download the tex files. I found the sty files. I couldn't get it to work in the MikTex files, but I *DID* get it to compile in the folder itself with the tex file I was creating by pasting all of the sty files from thmtools. There are so many .sty files in that folder right now from this quick workaround.

I've ran into this issue before on my previous computer. I'm wondering if there's a better and more permanent way to fix this so that I don't just end up with a massive amount of .sty files. I always just copy and paste from my previous folder when creating a new one.

Comment: Hello I'm the current maintainer of `thmtools`. When uploading `thmtools` v0.72 to CTAN, I made a mistake to not pack the `.ins` file. This mistake will prohibit getting `.sty` from `.dtx`, hence caused your problem on MiKTeX. On CTAN file `.ins` is back on around Aug 3, and I've reported this to MiKTeX, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/186. (The better and more permanent way is to wait MiKTeX to fix this problem caused by myself.) Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for the response and details! Also, thanks for maintaining the package =). I can just keep the .sty files inside the folder for now. That's always a nice and easy quick fix =).

Comment: I am getting the same error too! `File 'thmtools.sty' not found.` Perhaps the best as said is to keep the `thmtools.sty` files inside the working folder and then wait for MiKTeX fix.

Comment: @Ecoi @hesham MiKTeX has fixed the problem, you can try to upgrade `thmtools`.

Comment: This is the latest version available on CTAN `72 2020-08-01` . Do you mean this or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558698/thmtools-sty-not-found-miktex-console-issue#comment1409009_558698), this is a problem caused by wrongly packed `thmtools` (which was packed by myself). Thanks to Christian Schenk, the maintainer of MiKTeX, it has been resolved on Aug 18, 2020 (check [here](https://miktex.org/packages/thmtools/files) to see the `.sty` files are back).

Comment: This is CTAN page that get https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools?lang=en . The latest update date says `72 2020-08-01`

Comment: [UPDATE] The Miktex has updated successfully to the `thmtools` version `2020-08-17`. Now any source containing `\usepackage{thmtools}` compiles successfully. Thanks for the maintainer and the OP.

Comment: @hesham Yes it is `thmtools 72 2020-08-01`. You can think that there was a wrong upgrade to `thmtools 72` provided by MiKTeX, and now it is fixed without bumping the  version number.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I just got confused between Aug 1 and Aug 18.